# Trying to add text at the end of a file in Ada

Tags: ada

I am using Ada for the first time and have a txt file with the following written on it

```
      23.000000#:599.659058,-67.651642
```

I want to add an R, in a newline in the archive so it ends like this

```
      23.000000#:599.659058,-67.651642
      R,
```

For that I am using the following code

```
  Open (File => out_parcial_variante1, Name => "c.txt", Mode => out_file);
    new_line(out_parcial_variante1);
    put(File => out_parcial_variante1, Item=> "R,");
  close(out_parcial_variante1);
```

However doing this deletes all previous written data in the archive, leaving only the new line and a sole R,

How do I exactly append to the end of the file this text, I can seem to find the function and this is the only way I can think of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try append_file instead of out_file: `Open (File => out_parcial_variante1, Name => "c.txt", Mode => Append_File);`

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the accepted answer: "out_file" mode creates a brand new file to write to (wiping out any file already there). Similarly, parameters of mode "out" have no defined initial value (even if your actual parameter you supply may have been initialized to something), and should not be read from before initialized. In Ada, "out" and "in" mean what they say. :-)

Comment: Sometimes I wish they'd named "Append_File" to "In_Out_File" for consistency with the argument above. :-)

Comment: Text_IO.Append_File doesn't let you go back in the file. Direct_IO, which does, has mode [Inout_File](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-8-4.html#p4).